# Regex to replace multiple spaces at the end of line with comma or add comma

Tags: regex, textpad

I'm using Regex and TextPad to clean up and prep sql scripts. I want to replace with comma or add comma:

- 1 or more spaces at the end of each line
- at end of each line or the last line (i.e. "end of file")

After spending a few hours researching and iterating I came up with the following which is close to the desired result I want but not perfect. How do I edit this to get the below desired result?

**Find what:** `' +$|(\n)|$(?![\r\n])'`

**Replace with:** `'\1\2,'`

I have data that looks like

```
       dog  *(2 spaces)*
        cat    *(4 spaces)*
        bird*(no space)*
       rodent *(1 space)*
      fish*(no space)*
```

I want the result to be

```
    dog,
    cat,
    bird,
    rodent,
    fish,
```

My result  is

```
        dog,
         cat,
         bird
    ,     rodent,
         fish,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating it. Just match any number of spaces at the end of the line, and replace with comma.

Find: `\s*$`
Replace with: `,`

Comment: Just to mention this [can be inefficent](https://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2016/07/21/the-regex-that-killed-stackoverflow/) and depending on lang/tool result in [undesired matches](https://regex101.com/r/qbbXgt/1). An idea to prevent it can be to [replace `^(.*\S)?\s*$` with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/qbbXgt/3), (capturing up to last non-white-space).

Comment: You should post that as a new answer, with a full explanation of why mine fails and this is better.

Answer (score 3):

In *textpad* or *notepad++* `\s*$` will work but it's worth to mention that if using this in another environment it can lead to [undesired matches (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/qbbXgt/1) and add an extra comma if there are spaces at the end of the line. The reason is that for example in        `cat`    it will match the spaces after         `cat` (*first match*) plus a zero-length match at end of the line (*second match*).

Another potential issue of `\s*$` can be read here: [The RegEx that killed StackOverflow (blog)](https://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2016/07/21/the-regex-that-killed-stackoverflow/)

If there are many spaces inside the text it can lead to a lot of backtracking [(regex101 demo)](https://regex101.com/r/3rD7er/1). This demo input needs about 7k steps just to remove some spaces at the end. A workaround to reduce steps can be to *consume* and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the part up to the last [non-white-space](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated) (if there is one).

```
^(.*\S)?\s*$
```

[Replace with `$1,` (regex101 demo)](https://regex101.com/r/3rD7er/2) what's captured by the first group which is set to [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) for even matching only whitespace. This would get it down to a bit more than 100 steps.